# How to make bootable usb from part iso files?

Tags: usb, iso

I am trying to make a bootable usb disk for a linux distro. The image files i downloaded is in parts like `linux_dvd1of3.iso`, `linux_dvd2of3.iso`, `linux_dvd3of3.iso`. I want to write these part iso files into usb to create a bootable usb disk. How can I make a bootable usb disk using these part iso files?

Comment: Are there only 3 parts?

Comment: How large are each of the files? I would expect this: mount all 3, copy ISO 2 and ISO 3 to ISO 1. Create new ISO from ISO 1.

Comment: I would use something like GParted to create three partitions on your USB, one for each iso. I haven't tried that but I think that will work.

Answer (score 1):

1.First thing is merge three ISO files into one using ISO processing tools.

Go to this link for how to merge http://www.ehow.com/how_8771531_combine-multiple-iso-files-one.html

2.Then format your pen drive using NTFS format.

3.Extract the single Merged file directly to the pend-rive using power ISO.
i.e. select destination as your pend-rive while burning or extracting image file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to join all ISO in a single ISO. To do this, start mounting each ISO:

```
mkdir /tmp/dvd1 /tmp/dvd2 /tmp/dvd3
mount -o loop linux_dvd1of3.iso /tmp/dvd1
mount -o loop linux_dvd2of3.iso /tmp/dvd2
mount -o loop linux_dvd3of3.iso /tmp/dvd3
```

Now you can join all files:

```
mkisofs -o linux_dvd.iso /tmp/dvd1 /tmp/dvd2 /tmp/dvd3
```

The final step is to use [unetbootin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=unetbootin) to create a bootable USB with your final image.

```
apt-get install unetbootin
```

P.S.: Run all commands as root.

As a normal user, use the unetbootin to create the bootable USB (it's simple, and has GUI).